# What is the syntax for providing a hyperlink (with a link description) in comments

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

The [comments help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) says:

Hyperlinks can be formatted as `[basic links](http://example.com)`

Then I write `[This is a link description](http://linkurl.com)` and the result is unexpected.

(You can see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383656/when-should-i-use-class-object-class-module-module-kernel-and-nothing/5384324#5384324).)

What am I doing wrong?

If the comment help is ambiguous, how do I notify StackOverflow to turn it better?

Comment: [link]http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000478)

Comment: Ok, trying again: [link to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85389/159586). Did it work?

Comment: I also experienced that a comment with a mix of raw link http://stackoverflow.com and a [nice link](http://stackoverflow.com) causes the raw link not being parsed as a link.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Even with my original link: [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classe/Module.html#M000478). I don't know what happened. It seems I can't edit that comment now. I guess I must close this question.

Comment: @Chichiray: raw link: http://stackoverflow.com. Nice link: [this is a nice link](http://stackoverflow.com). Mixed link: [http://stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com). Oh, I got it! I will try with ony a raw link.

Comment: This is actually unrelated to your *actual* problam :)

Comment: This is a raw link: http://stackoverflow.com. (Sorry for using this comments for testing; if there's a sandbox, I don't know it.)

Comment: Sandbox is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), but you can test as much as you want on your own posts, as no one gets @ notified and you can just blow away the comments when you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I could reproduce the exact comment is with a missing open round bracket:

`[link]http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000478)`

Try again using the complete syntax.

Comment: After some tests, I believe that is what happened. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Sony: Glad I could help.