# Relationships Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

All the time I've got questions about relationships.  Stack-exchange is where I turn to get ideas for many other questions, why not in the realm of love and friendship and sex?  Example question:

I broke up with a person I'd gone on a dozen dates with, but told them we could still be friends.  Now they want to hang out every other day.  How can I tell them I want to see them less often without a specific reason?

Comment: Area 51 is the place for new stack exchange sites, but this sounds a little 'yahoo answers' for my liking

Comment: Will the questions and answers this site would generate be useful to future users or just a support group. Your example question suggests the later

Comment: Those types of questions tend to be very localized; what works for one person may not apply to anyone else. Can you think of any questions in the "relationship" topic that would have definitive, broadly applicable answers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a site proposal, which belongs on Area 51.  See the [Relationships & Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) proposal.

Comment: Area 51 has a proposal called [Relationships and Dating][1] which is supposed to become the *Q&A site for people seeking answers to questions about dating, long term relationships, love, marriage or other commitments, and everything else typically considered a "relationship"* Should you be interested in this proposal, you can support it.


  [1]: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating

Comment: @AlexanderSerebrenik See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85389/what-is-the-syntax-for-providing-a-hyperlink-with-a-link-description-in-commen) or [comment help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for how to format comment links

Comment: @RichardTingle thank you for your advice!

Comment: @RichardTingle I find it slightly amusing that you were attracted to this question.

Comment: It's a pity this is the first result when I searched for mathematical relations on math stack exchange :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sample question would not fit the stack exchange model under *any* topic.  Answers would be based entirely on opinion.

Comment: I personally unsupport relationships myself. It's a sore point. It doesn't fit the main point of SE model (together with self-help answers). I must admit it's a woe of many forums, that makes and makes precedence. So this question must be deleted ASAP. Also, by downvoting that-like question one just supports such topics. +don't touch!

Comment: You're right, it was a dumb idea :(  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/